# How i can use cursor to delete record from table

Tags: sql-server, database-cursor

I want to use cursor to delete record from table. How can I do it?

I use MSSQL 2008 Express this code does not delete anything from #temp. I also tried where current of cursor_name did not work.

Here is my sample code:

```
use AdventureWorks

drop table #temp
select * into #temp from HumanResources.Employee;

declare @eid as int;
declare @nid as varchar(15);


DECLARE Employee_Cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT A.EmployeeID, A.NationalIDNumber FROM #temp AS A
OPEN Employee_Cursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM Employee_Cursor INTO @eid , @nid ;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
   BEGIN
      IF (@eid > 10)
      BEGIN
        delete from #temp where #temp.EmployeeID = @eid;
      END
      FETCH NEXT FROM Employee_Cursor;
   END;
CLOSE Employee_Cursor;
DEALLOCATE Employee_Cursor;
GO

select * from #temp
```

thanks in advance

Comment: For the love of all that's holy, why are you using a cursor to do that instead of a simple delete query? Do you have a grudge against your DBA?

Comment: Silly question but do you have any EmployeeID > 10 in the Employee table??  Also why do you want to do a cursor for this?  It is a very inefficient method.
Also make sure there are no triggers that are aborting your deletion.

Comment: @JohnFx no i am just curious to do it , just to learn ,in practice i too use simple delete statements

Comment: @JohnFX Maybe he just wants to make sure to create as much contention as possible :D  A cursor on TempDB seems a good way. j/k vivek kinda.

Comment: @vivek - Don't practice evil. You might get good at it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
use AdventureWorks

select * into #temp from HumanResources.Employee;

declare @eid as int;
declare @nid as varchar(15);

DECLARE Employee_Cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT A.EmployeeID, A.NationalIDNumber FROM #temp AS A
OPEN Employee_Cursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM Employee_Cursor INTO @eid , @nid ;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
   BEGIN
      IF (@eid > 10)
      BEGIN
        delete from #temp where current of Employee_Cursor
      END
      FETCH NEXT FROM Employee_Cursor INTO @eid , @nid ;
   END;
CLOSE Employee_Cursor;
DEALLOCATE Employee_Cursor;

select * from #temp

drop table #temp
```

this works for me

Answer (score 6):

There is a much simpler answer - use this command:

```
delete from HumanResources.Employee where current of Employee_Cursor
```

It's called 'Positioned delete' and described at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189835.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try in below ways, thanks for your time.

You have fetched data from cursor but didn't push into your variables missed in `WHILE` loop, please have a look on below code, thanks.

```
drop table #temp
select * into #temp from Employee;

declare @eid as int;
declare @nid as varchar(15);


DECLARE Employee_Cursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT A.EmployeeID, A.NationalIDNumber FROM #temp AS A

OPEN Employee_Cursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM Employee_Cursor INTO @eid , @nid ;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
   BEGIN
      IF (@eid > 10)
      BEGIN
        delete from #temp where #temp.EmployeeID = @eid;
      END
      FETCH NEXT FROM Employee_Cursor INTO @eid , @nid ;
   END;
CLOSE Employee_Cursor;
DEALLOCATE Employee_Cursor;
GO

select * from #temp
```

**Update:**
I've changes in 2nd `FETCH` statement, just have added below highlighted part, thanks

FETCH NEXT FROM Employee_Cursor **INTO @eid , @nid** ;

Comment: how it is different from my one ? , well i tried but did not work ,anyway thanks for u r interest

Comment: Sorry, for late reply, however, I'm going to change my answer, please have a look on it, thanks

Comment: When the code looks so similar to the original, it's usually quite helpful to highlight what's been changed (I assume it's adding the `INTO` onto the second `FETCH`, since that's what I was about to answer)

Comment: well i got answer but can not post it

Comment: @Elias Hossain yes it works but why two tables ,i think it can be done with one i just post one way, check that as well, thanks for taking interest